# Let $f$ be increasing on $[a,b]$ and $a < x_1 < \dotsb < x_n < b$. Show that $\sum_{k = 1}^n [f(x_k^+) - f(x_k^-)]\leq f(b^-) - f(a^+)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

> Let $f$ be an increasing function defined on $[a,b]$ and let $x_1 < x_2 < \dotsb < x_n$ be $n$ points in the interior of $[a,b]$. Show that $\sum_{k = 1}^n [f(x_k^+) - f(x_k^-)]\leq f(b^-) - f(a^+)$.

The proof I have is very wordy and sketchy. I know it would be easier if I could find a telescoping sum but I've got a road block in my mind. :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, define $x_0 = a$ and $x_{n+1}=b$.
Then, for any $k=1,\ldots,n$, we have
$$
f(x_k +)-f(x_k -) \leq f\bigg(\frac{{x_k  + x_{k + 1} }}{2}\bigg) - f\bigg(\frac{{x_{k - 1}  + x_k }}{2}\bigg)
$$
(since $f$ is increasing). Thus,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {[f(x_k  + ) - f(x_k  - )]}  \le f\bigg(\frac{{x_n  + x_{n + 1} }}{2}\bigg) - f\bigg(\frac{{x_0  + x_1 }}{2}\bigg).
$$
Now, since $(x_n  + x_{n + 1} )/2 = (x_n  + b)/2 < b$ and $(x_0  + x_1 )/2 = (a  + x_1)/2 > a$, we get
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {[f(x_k  + ) - f(x_k  - )]}  \le f(b-) - f(a+).
$$