# Let $f$ be increasing and $x_1 < \dotsb < x_n$ in $[a,b]$. Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n o(f,x_i) < f(b)-f(a)$, where $o$ is the oscillation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

Let $f$ be increasing on $[a,b]$, take points $x_1 < \dotsb < x_n$ in $[a,b]$. I am trying to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n o(f,x_i) < f(b)-f(a)$ where $o(f,x_i) $ is the [oscillation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_%28mathematics%29) of the function at $x_i$.

Here is what I have done: for any $\delta$, $$M(x_i,f,\delta)-m(x_i,f,\delta)\le f(\min(x_i+\delta,b))-f(\max(x_i+\delta,a))$$ where $M(a,f,\delta)$ is $\sup \{f(x)\}$ for $x$ in a $\delta$-neighborhood of $a$, and $m$ is the infimum. The oscillation is the limit of the difference as $\delta \to 0$. I have an upper bound for the oscillation, but I can't find a way to make the terms cancel out when I add them.

Comment: Since $f$ is monotonic, the oscillation is the difference of the one-sided limits.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please elaborate I didn't understand how this helps.

Comment: $f$ is increasing here, so $$\sup \left\lbrace f(x) : x \in (x_i-\delta, x_i+\delta)\right\rbrace = f(x_i+\delta^-) = \lim_{h\searrow 0} f(x_i+\delta-h),$$ similarly for the infimum. Then $$\lim_{\delta\searrow 0} M(x_i,f,\delta) = \lim_{h\searrow 0} f(x_i+h) = f(x_i^+).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer So this gives that $o(f,x_i)=f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)$, right?

Comment: Yep, the difference between the one-sided limits.

Comment: So I now have to show that $\sum f(x_i^+)-f(x_i^-)
<f(b)-f(a)$ which I think is done here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/inequality-on-an-increasing-function?rq=1

Comment: I can. A few minutes patience, slow typist.

Comment: This is problem 1-30 calculus on manifolds by Spivak. Increasing function in all of Spivak's books means that "strictly increasing function". Hence the inequality is strictly i. e. $\sum_{i=1}^n o(f,x_i) < f(b)-f(a)$. But for non-decreasing (non strictly increasing) function $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we have    $\sum_{i=1}^n o(f,x_i) \leq f(b)-f(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function is increasing, we have

$$\tilde{M}(x_i,f,\delta) := \sup \left\lbrace f(x) : x \in [x_i-\delta, x_i +\delta]\right\rbrace = f(x_i+\delta)$$

and similarly $\tilde{m}(x_i,f,\delta) = f(x_i-\delta)$. Using a closed interval instead of an open one simplifies matters here, otherwise we'd have to use the one-sided limits of $f$ at $x_i \pm\delta$. It does not influence the oscillation, since for $0 < \delta < \delta'$ we have $M(x_i,f,\delta) \leqslant \tilde{M}(x_i,f,\delta) \leqslant M(x_i,f,\delta')$ and similarly for the infima.

That gives us

$$o(f,x_i) = \lim_{\delta\searrow 0} \left(\tilde{M}(x_i,f,\delta) - \tilde{m}(x_i,f,\delta)\right) = f(x_i^+) - f(x_i^-).$$

Now to obtain the estimate for the sum of oscillations, use intermediate points $y_i = \frac12(x_i + x_{i+1})$, where we add $x_0 = a$ and $x_{n+1} = b$ if the two are not among the $x_i$, otherwise let $y_0 = a$ resp. $y_{n} = b$. Then $x_{i} < y_i < x_{i+1}$, except perhaps at the endpoints of the interval, and

$$\sum_{i=1}^n o(f,x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n (f(x_i^+) - f(x_i^-)) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n (f(y_i) - f(y_{i-1}) = f(y_n) - f(y_0) \leqslant f(b) - f(a).$$

Comment: you mean to say that what is in the comments is wrong if the regular $M$'s are taken?

Comment: No, it makes no difference, since we take the limit $\delta\to 0$. I just thought it might be good to show that we can also use closed intervals to determine the oscillation (that is generally true, doesn't require monotonicity).

Comment: I am totally confused now, you said if one doesn't use closed intervals we get one sided limits of $x_i \pm\delta$.

Comment: Yes. If we use open intervals, we get $M(x_i,f,\delta) = f((x_i+\delta)^-)$. That may or may not be the same value as $f(x_i+\delta)$. But since for the oscillation we take the limit, and every closed $[x_i-\delta,x_i+\delta]$ 1. contains an open $(x_i-\delta,x_i+\delta)$ and 2. is contained in a slightly larger open interval, the result for the oscillation is the same.